# tsunami windows 10 curl java home environment variable error

Tags: windows, windows-10, bash, java, curl

I am setting up tsunami on Windows 10. I am following the tutorial (https://github.com/google/tsunami-security-scanner). When I run the `bash` command, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.
```

When I run `echo %JAVA_HOME%`, I get

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_351
```

What possible explanation could there be for this?

The role of the `bash -c "$(curl -sfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/tsunami-security-scanner/master/quick_start.sh)"` command is described at https://github.com/google/tsunami-security-scanner.

Comment: Where do you get your bash? WSL? `echo %JAVA_HOME%` doesn't look bash.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install this from a Windows CMD window. You need to be already inside WSL or using a Linux-based distribution.

Environment variables for Windows (such as your `%JAVA_HOME%` are not the same as environment variables in WSL (or the `bash` command that runs under WSL):

```
C:\Users\Chris>set DDD=three ds
C:\Users\Chris>echo %DDD%
three ds

C:\Users\Chris>bash
Debian:chris:/mnt/c/Users/Chris$ echo $DDD
```

On the other hand, if you're using Cygwin the environment variables are inherited (but you'll have other issues such as the `$PATH` probably not being set correctly for it to work):

```
C:\Users\Chris>c:\cygwin\bin\bash
$ echo $DDD
three ds
```